# SML List Deletion

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I am trying to write a function to delete a list from another list.

```
''a list -> ''a list -> ''a list
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
fun delete  _ [] = [] | 
    delete (h1::t1) (h2::t2) = 
     if h1=h2
     then t2
     else h2::delete (h1::t1) t2;
```

I am using MoscowML and it gives me a *Warning: pattern matching is not exhaustive* error.

A test of the above function:

```
- delete [4,5] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
> val it = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8] : int list
```

The desired output is:

```
> val it = [1,2,3,6,7,8] : int list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1- Why is the interpreter raising the Warning: pattern matching is not exhaustive error

2- What can be done to make the code working.

Concerning the first point, the reason for the warning is because that you are not checking every possibility that may occur. The function `delete` as it currently stands checks only for two possibilities:

-1 The second list being the empty list (covered by the pattern: `_ [] =` )

-2 Both lists not being empty (covered by the second pattern: `(h1::t1) (h2::t2) =`)

However, there is a third possibility, namely the first list being the empty list. Therefore, the following input would result in an error: `delete [] [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Concerning the second point, if the exact requirement is to delete from the second list the elements of the first list in succession and only once, then your solution is very close. The `else` branch is fine, only the `then` branch needs more attention.
By correcting the `then` branch I get following results:

```
delete [4,5] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] = [1,2,3,6,7,8];
delete [5,4] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8];
delete [4,4,5] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8];
delete [4,5,6] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] = [1,2,3,7,8];
delete [4,6,5] [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] = [1,2,3,5,7,8];
delete [4,6,5] [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,5] = [1,2,3,7,8];
```

If however you want to delete all the elements of the first list occurring in the second list regardless of their order, then you will need to rethink your approach.

for instance, if you want the following result:

`delete [4,6,5] [1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,4,4,6,6,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,5] = [1,2,3,7,8];`

then you need to do it in two steps:
First write a function `del` that given one element will delete all its occurrences in a list: `fun del e l = ...`
The implementation thereof is practically identical to the one you provided for `delete`, except you will need to change the `then` branch slightly.

After you have `del`, now you can implement the function `delete` that given a list, it will delete all the occurrences of that list in the second list. Here you will use the previously defined function `del`.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting answer! My initial goal was to just delete elements in the same order as the first list but now this has helped me view it differently. I managed to fix the code by correcting the 'then' branch!